# Is it possible to retrieve an image from the data folder in an android app?

Tags: android

I want to retrieve an image from my data/data/com.apps.myapp/images folder and display it in an ImageView. Any clue?

Comment: a very broad question that looks like you just want someone to pass you some example code to faster get an answer start programming and then describe your problems give us examples what you have done so far etc.

Comment: it's always nice to ist do a little search and than try posting it on community to assist you...

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("data/data/com.apps.myapp/images/img.png");
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imgViewId);

imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several components involved in this. 
To get the path of your data folder you can use the method [getDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) in the Context.
Now you have to know the file name and open an stream here again the Context class is your [friend](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29). Now the stream can be [decoded](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) into a Bitmap via a Bitmap Factory.
After you got a Bitmap create a [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) from it and pass it to your ImageView